# How to specify credential to access shared folder

Tags: c#

I have a window service that needs to access a shared folder to check a file.  Currently I use:

```
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(excelFile))
```

where excelFile is: `\\isgisdb01\GIS_projects\Garage_sales\GarageSales.xls`

That results in an error: file not found

So I added a service account to the Garage_sales folder.  How do I assign the service account credentials to my code so it would get the permission it needs?

Comment: You can do it using impersonate [See this][1] for how to impersonate in .Net


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net

Comment: I got it to work using your advice.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do that through the service control manager where you tell the service under what credentials to execute.

Comment: I went into the property of the window service and change from Local System to the service account that I just created, but I don't think that makes sense.  Can I just leave it as Local System and supply the credentials when I access the file?

Comment: You can but you will need to impersonate that account before you attempt to access the file.